# VBA does not recognize headers from Listed Objects

Tags: excel, vba

I cannot understand why excel stopped recognizing the headers of listed objects; specifically this line `Range("Offer_Table[[#Headers], [LOC]").Select`
I would like to change the format of specific header and I first was able to do it using the following code.

```
Range("Offer_Table[[#Headers], [LOC]").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

however, the code stopped working once I closed all active sheets to run a  first complete test on a new sheet. I do not understand why but headers now are no longer recognized by Excel. Either if I create a new LO from VBA or I do it manually setting a new table.

Below is the sample code

```
'Referring to the Table
    Dim Offer_table As ListObject
    CntCol = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)).Count
    CntRow = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Count


MsgBox CntCol
MsgBox CntRow
    Set Offer_table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(CntRow, CntCol)), , xlYes)
    Offer_table.Name = "Offer_Table"
    Offer_table.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"


'Highlight headers
        Range("Offer_Table[[#Headers], [Order Creation]").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

         Range("Offer_Table[[#Headers],[SEGMENT]").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and [The VBA Guide To ListObject Excel Tables](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables).

Comment: Also note that `Range("Offer_Table[[#Headers], [LOC]").Select` should be `Range("Offer_Table[[#Headers], [LOC]]").Select`. Since there are two opening brackets, there should also be two closing brackets as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is caused due to you not explicitly referencing where your table is. You also declare it as a `ListObject` and then don't use it when referring to it later on. Have a look at the following. Make sure to update the `With Activesheet` to the explicit reference of the sheet with the table on otherwise as soon as you move to another sheet you will run into issues again

```
'Referring to the Table
Dim Offer_table As ListObject
Dim CntCol As Long, CntRow As Long

' Update with reference to your sheet
With ActiveSheet
    CntCol = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)).Count
    CntRow = Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Count

    MsgBox CntCol & vbNewLine & CntRow

    Set Offer_table = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(CntRow, CntCol)), , xlYes)
    Offer_table.Name = "Offer_Table"
    Offer_table.TableStyle = "TableStyleLight2"
End With

'Highlight headers
' Range("Offer_Table[[#Headers], [Order Creation]").Select
With Offer_table
    With .HeaderRowRange(.ListColumns("Order Creation").Range.Column)
        With .Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
            .Size = 11
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        End With
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With

    ' Range("Offer_Table[[#Headers],[SEGMENT]").Select
    With Offer_table.HeaderRowRange(.ListColumns("SEGMENT").Range.Column)
        With .Font
            .Name = "Calibri"
            .FontStyle = "Bold"
            .Size = 11
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
            .TintAndShade = -0.249977111
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
        End With
        With .Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End With
```